# about hibernate cache store

Tags: hibernate, caching

As we know, hibernate has L1 and L2 cache.  Now I have some questions about their store :

1. If L2 cache enabled and there is no hit in L1 and L2 cache, then hibernate will query DB.  However, after getting result from DB, it will store the result in L2 cache only or both L1 and L2 or anything else?
2. If L2 cache enabled and L1 of one session has result but L2 has not, then hibernate will copy this result from L1 to L2?
3. If L2 cache enabled and L2 has result but L1 has not, then hibernate will copy it from L2 to L1?

**update**

**4. If I have next code and without L2 cache and query cache :**

> ```
> List<Student> persons = session.createQuery("from Student").list();
>
> List<Student> students = session.createQuery("from Student").list();
> ```

why hibernate will query DB twice? Doesn't it has L1 cache, then it only query DB at first time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> If L2 cache enabled and there is no hit in L1 and L2 cache, then hibernate will query DB. However, after getting result from DB, it will store the result in L2 cache only or both L1 and L2 or anything else?

This depends entirely what type of operation you are attempting to perform

1. `EntityManager.find()`

   In this case, so long as the entity is configured with `@Cachable` and L2 cache is enabled, any result you receive from these lookups will be cached both in L1 and L2 and will be kept in L2 based on your L2 cache configurations.
2. `EntityManager.createQuery()`

   In this case, it not only depends on whether the entity is configured with `@Cachable` and that L2 cache is enabled, but whether or not *Query Cache* is enabled either globally via a configuration property `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true` or whether you specify that a specific query is cachable via `query.setCachable(true)` at runtime.

   If the query isn't cached and subsequent sessions run the same query, the L2 cache will not be consulted because the query has no prior knowledge of what entity identifiers are mapped to the executing query, thus the datasource must be consulted via a SQL query.

> If L2 cache enabled and L1 of one session has result but L2 has not, then hibernate will copy this result from L1 to L2?

See my above answer.

If you executed `entityManager.find()`, then yes L2 would be hydrated with the attribute data of the entity you just queried if it was a cachable entity instance.

If you executed `entityManager.createQuery()`, this will depend on whether query cache is enabled.  If it isn't enabled, then no data will be copied to L2.  If query cache is enabled, then L2 would be updated accordingly as indicated above.

> If L2 cache enabled and L2 has result but L1 has not, then hibernate will copy it from L2 to L1?

The L1 cache will always have the active state of an attached entity, regardless of whether the state was fetched from the L2 cache, the datastore, or a combination of both.

> If I have 2 "session.createQuery(..).list()" within one session, why hibernate will query DB twice? Doens't it has L1 cache, then the second "session.createQuery(...).list()" should get the result from the L1?

I am going to assume both queries execute the same HQL statement as that is a requirement for query caching to work for this use case.

Just because Hibernate issues queries to the database during a query doesn't imply that the L2 cache isn't being consulted or used.

First, are both queries using `setCachable(true)` to enable query cache?

Assuming the query cache and entity cache were empty at the execution of your first `list()`, hibernate would populate both the entity and query cache accordingly.  During the second query, it would consult the L2 cache and so long as neither entity or query cache had expired, it would rehydrate from L2.

It is important to note that if the query cache expires after your entity cache results, this can create some performance bottleneck issues as the L2 query cache will indicate which entities to include, hibernate will find they're expired and will reissue database queries for each expired entity by id.

Comment: `The L1 cache will always have the active state of an attached entity, regardless of whether the state was fetched from the L2 cache, the datastore, or a combination of both`, what do you mean?

Comment: `If I have 2 "session.createQuery(..).list()" within one session, why hibernate will query DB twice? Doens't it has L1 cache, then the second "session.createQuery(...).list()" should get the result from the L1?`, I have modified this question, plz see my updated.